# CardsUI for Android setScrollListener

Tags: android, eclipse, listener, google-now

I am attempting to use Navadfima's CardsUI for Android [here](https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android).  The problem is I have approximately 1500 bitmaps (each one goes on a card) and even when using the scaling suggestions at the [DevDocs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) I run out of memory.  My current plan is to set an onScrollListener in the CardUI activity but I don't know how to make one in a library that I can call from my code.

CardUI class from Library is [here](https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android/blob/master/CardsUILib/src/com/fima/cardsui/views/CardUI.java)

My class:

```
public class FragmentCardsUI extends Fragment{
private CardUI mCardView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("Cards UI");

    // init CardView
    mCardView = (CardUI) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardsview);

    try {
        setCards();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mCardView.refresh();
return rootView;
```

How can I modify CardUI so I can set an onScrollListener in my code so I can tell when a card is visible and subsequently load a bitmap to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found a good solution for this so I switched libraries to use [Nostra's Universal Image Loader](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader&ei=2lQKUoHePJT22QWPtYDwCw&usg=AFQjCNGgmKC8hBtbywLST53tMmNnUAuNQA&sig2=WjuZf_NUxb4Ax40WCjXLiQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.b2I&cad=rja).  This library appears to still be in development as opposed to the CardsUI library (hasn't had a change in over 7 months but there are plenty of requests).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into com.fima.cardsui.StackAdapter.java getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final CardStack stack = getItem(position);
    stack.setAdapter(this);
    stack.setPosition(position);

    // TODO: caching is not working well

    // if (convertView != null) {
    // CardStack tagStack = (CardStack) convertView.getTag();
    // ArrayList<Card> tagCards = tagStack.getCards();
    // ArrayList<Card> cards = stack.getCards();
    // Card lastTagCard = tagCards.get(tagCards.size()-1);
    // if (!lastTagCard.equals(cards.get(cards.size()-1))) {
    // convertView = stack.getView(mContext);
    // convertView.setTag(stack);
    // }
    // } else if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = stack.getView(mContext, mSwipeable);
    // convertView.setTag(stack);
    // }

    return convertView;
}
```

I believe, that's the reason you are getting OME. It doesn't use ViewHolder pattern, instead it tries to load everything again.

Also looked into com.fima.cardsui.objects.CardStack and you can guess what happens when you try to create 1500 Views.

I recommend you to modify the source.

Comment: So you believe a ViewHolder will solve the problem?  I assumed I was getting the OME due to the large number of bitmaps and no caching.  I'll try modifying to include the ViewHolder (never heard of it before but it sounds useful).

Comment: Tried looking into adding a ViewHolder but I'm not sure where it would go...I also looked into CardStack and can't see what should be modified under getView

Comment: The concept of using ViewHolder is to load only visible views. So lets say you have 10 visible Bitmaps, which means you won't load other 1490 Bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

In case u want to implement the scroll down for the CardsUI Lib . Just add the following :

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

You need to add the lines in cards_view.xml Layout . Here is how the file will look after update :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.fima.cardsui.views.QuickReturnListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
</com.fima.cardsui.views.QuickReturnListView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sticky"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```